# Dropdown dependent on another dropdown dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Sorry if this is was discussed before but based on my observation and trials. All of them doesn't work. I have 5 dropdowns,They are **brand,model,color,engine no. and chasis no.**. What javascript function should I use, to make the dropdown of the model that was depend of the selected brand,the dropdown of color is depend to the selected model and the dropdown engine no. and chasis no is depend to the selected color.

Here's my code

```html
 <label for="bName" class="control-label col-xs-4"><p class="left">Brand</p></label>
 <div class="col-xs-7">
 <div class="req">
   <?php
include_once "config.php";

             $bsql="SELECT bName, brandID FROM brand order by bName"; 
   $bstmt=$con->prepare($bsql);
   $bstmt->execute();
  $bstmt->bind_result($bName, $bid);
  $bstmt->store_result();

             echo "<select name='brandID' class='form-control'>
              <option value=''></option>";

             while ($bstmt->fetch()){
 echo '<option value="'.$bid.'">'.$bName.'</option>';
             }

echo '</select>';
?>
   </div>
<div class="col-xs-1">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
         
<label for="model" class="control-label col-xs-4"><p class="left">Model</p></label>
<div class="col-xs-7">
<div class="req"> 
 
 <?php
include_once "config.php";

             $msql="SELECT model, modID FROM model where brandID=? order by model"; 
$mstmt=$con->prepare($msql);
$mstmt->bind_param('i', $bid)

$mstmt->execute();
$mstmt->bind_result($model, $mid);
$mstmt->store_result();

echo "<select name='mID' class='form-control'>
<option value=''></option>";

while ($mstmt->fetch()){  echo '<option value="'.$mid.'">'.$model.'</option>';
             }
echo '</select>';
            
             ?>
             
</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">
</div>
</div> 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="color" class="control-label col-xs-4"><p class="left">Color</p></label>
<div class="col-xs-7">
<select ="color" class="req">
 <option value='blue'>Blue</option>
 <option value='red'>Red</option>
 </select>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-1">
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="form-group">
<label for="engine"  class="control-label col-xs-4"><p class="left">Engine No.</p></label>
<div class="col-xs-7">
<select name="engine"  class="req" required/>
<option></option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-1">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
         
<label for="chasis"  class="control-label col-xs-4"><p class="left">Chasis No.</p></label>
<div class="col-xs-7">
<select name="chasis"  class="req" required/>
<option></option>
            
</select>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-1">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem here?? dropdown or your php code?

Comment: dropdown that depends on another dropdown

Comment: @Flido you can check my new question I elaborate and expound more my problem. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33094136/dropdown-that-based-on-another-dropdown-select-option-are-from-database

Comment: Heyy sorry late get back to you. I will check it after this. Thanks!