# Dropdown that based on another dropdown, select option are from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Sorry if it was discussed before, but all of them doesn't really work for me. I have 5 dropdowns they are Brand, Model, Color, Engine No. and Chassis No., My question is what should I do to make the dropdown of the model is based on the selected dropdown of Brand, for example If a user selects Honda well based on my posted image in my database, the BrandID of Honda is 1 so all of the model that has the BrandID = 1. The dropdown of the model shown are only that has a brandID =1. Then the dropdown of color is based on the dropdown of the model, so the same logic like I discussed earlier. Finally the Dropdown of Engine No. and Chasis No. is based on the dropdown of the color, also the same as the logic that I discussed.

**Here's my code for the brand dropdown**

```html
<label for="bName" class="control-label col-xs-4"><p class="left">Brand</p></label>
 <div class="col-xs-7">
   <div class="req"> 
   <?php
   include_once "config.php";

   $bsql="SELECT bName, brandID FROM brand order by bName"; 
    $bstmt=$con->prepare($bsql);
    $bstmt->execute();
   $bstmt->bind_result($bName, $bid);
   $bstmt->store_result();

  echo "<select name='brandID' class='form-control'>
  <option value=''></option>";

  while ($bstmt->fetch()){
 echo '<option value="'.$bid.'">'.$bName.'</option>';
            }

  echo '</select>';
            
             ?>
             
             </div>
            </div>
```

**Heres the code for the dropdown of the model**

```html
<label for="model" class="control-label col-xs-4">
  <p class="left">Model</p></label>
  <div class="col-xs-7">
 <div class="req"> 
 <?php
 include_once "config.php";

 $msql="SELECT model, modID FROM model order by model"; 
 $mstmt=$con->prepare($msql);
 //$mstmt->bind_param('i', $bid);
 $mstmt->execute();
 $mstmt->bind_result($model, $mid);
  $mstmt->store_result();

echo "<select name='mID' class='form-control'>
 <option value=''></option>";

 while ($mstmt->fetch()){
   echo '<option value="'.$mid.'">'.$model.'</option>';
             }
 echo '</select>';   
             ?>
             
    </div>
    </div>
```

**Heres the code for color dropdown**

```html
<label for="model" class="control-label col-xs-4"><p class="left">Color</p></label>
  <div class="col-xs-7">
  <div class="req"> 
  <?php
  include_once "config.php";

 $csql="SELECT distinct(color) FROM stock order by color"; 
 $cstmt=$con->prepare($csql);
             
 $cstmt->execute();
 $cstmt->bind_result($color);
 $cstmt->store_result();

echo "<select name='color' class='form-control'>
<option value=''></option>";

while ($cstmt->fetch()){
 echo '<option value="'.$color.'">'.$color.'</option>';
             }
  echo '</select>';   
             ?>
             
     </div>
     </div>
```

**Heres the code for the dropdown Engine No.**

```html
<label for="engNum" class="control-label col-xs-4">
  <p class="left">Engine No</p></label>
 <div class="col-xs-7">
 <div class="req"> 
 <?php
 include_once "config.php";

 $esql="SELECT engNum FROM stock where status='Available' order by engNum"; 
 $estmt=$con->prepare($esql);
 $estmt->execute();
 $estmt->bind_result($engNum);
 $estmt->store_result();

 echo "<select name='engNum' class='form-control'>
 <option value=''></option>";

 while ($estmt->fetch()){
 echo '<option value="'.$engNum.'">'.$engNum.'</option>';
             }

 echo '</select>';
            
   ?>
            
  </div>
  </div>
```

**Heres the code for the dropdown Chasis No.**

```html
<label for="chassisNum" class="control-label col-xs-4"><p class="left">Chassis No</p></label>
<div class="col-xs-7">
<div class="req"> 
<?php
include_once "config.php";

$nsql="SELECT chassisNum FROM stock where status='Available' order by chassisNum"; 
$nstmt=$con->prepare($nsql);
$nstmt->execute();
$nstmt->bind_result($chassisNum);
$nstmt->store_result();

echo "<select name='chassisNum' class='form-control'>
<option value=''></option>";

while ($nstmt->fetch()){
 echo '<option value="'.$chassisNum.'">'.$chassisNum.'</option>';
             }
echo '</select>';   
             ?>
             
 </div>
  </div>
```

**Heres the Image for my brand database**

[image]

**Heres the Image for my model database**

[image]

**Heres the Image for the color, chasis no. and engine no. database**

[image]

Comment: That's a whole load of data thrown our way, do you expect us to code for you?

Comment: Can you highlight the error? Thanks! :D

Comment: So you want your data put inside the dropdown?

Comment: @Flido the data is already in the dropdown based from my php code above, my problem is when I select the dropdown of Brand for example Honda only selected choices must be shown not all. Take a look of the BrandID above in my table. Honda's BrandID = 1, so if I select Honda in the dropdown of brand, the choices of dropdown of model == BrandID = 1.

Answer (score 3):

```
    Write an onchange event on select tag

    for e.g. to change the Models based on brand selected you should write


    <label for="bName" class="control-label col-xs-4"><p class="left">Brand</p></label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
        <div class="req">   
        <?php
        include_once "config.php";
        $bsql="SELECT bName, brandID FROM brand order by bName"; 
        $bstmt=$con->prepare($bsql);
        $bstmt->execute();
        $bstmt->bind_result($bName, $bid);
        $bstmt->store_result();

        echo "<select name='brandID' class='form-control' **onchange='getModels(this)'**>
            <option value=''></option>";

            while ($bstmt->fetch()){
                echo '<option value="'.$bid.'">'.$bName.'</option>';
                                }

        echo '</select>';

    //The function getModels(this) will get called whenever user will change the value of the brand option.

    Now define this method in your js file 


    function getModels(BrandObj)
    {
        brandValue=BrandObj.value; // Will give you the ID of brand which is selected.
        // Make A ajax call to some php file which will return models based on brand ID & bind it to your Models Dropdown
    $.ajax({
      url: 'getModels.php',
      type: 'GET', // Method Type 
      data: 'brandID=brandValue',// This parameter will be sent to getModels.php 
      success: function(**data**) {
        //called when successful the data we have returned in getModels.php will be accessible in "data" variable
        // Decode the response & bind it to your dropdownList

      },
      error: function(e) {
        //called when there is an error
        //console.log(e.message);
      }
    });


    }


// IN your getModels.php file write following code

$BrandID=@$_GET['brandID'];
//Connect to database
// Write a sql to find models having brand_id=$BrandID
// Fetch rows & create array of Models & return it using 
echo json_encode(*your_array_name*)

// END getModels.php

    // You can find the detailed documentation of AJAX
    http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
```

Comment: I'm truly sorry but I'm not really familiar with onchange event and ajax :(

Comment: "Make A ajax call to some php file which will return models based on brand ID & bind it to your Models Dropdown" If i found that, is that make things possible?

Comment: Well all my 5 dropdowns are in same php file